# Inherit routing from baseapi controller base to deriver controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .NET Core 3.0 Web API, I have a situation where I have set the prefix in the baseapicontroller and also set the route in the derived controller, theoretically I thought that it would work like "**baseapicontroller route/derived controller route**" but it is not working like that, .net core picks only the derived class route and ignore the baseapicontroller route.

I have tried to use the attribute "**Route**" and "**RoutePrefix**", it is still the same.

```
[ApiController]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
//[Route("api/v1")]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

derived controller

```
[Route("testing-route")]
public class TestRouteController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string test()
    {

        return "";
    }
}
```

I want the URL to be "**api/v1/testing-route/test**", I don't want to repeat **api/v1** in every controller. and also I know people might say that I can use "**api/v1/[controller]/[action]**" but that is not my requirement. I want to use the custom route for the controller.

Looking forward to get any good answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in `RouteAttribute` will not work with controller inheritance by default. However, to achieve your goal, you could create a custom [`IControllerModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to apply a rule that takes consideration of controller inheritance at startup-time.

#### How-to

To avoid mixing up with the default `[RouteAttribute]`, I create a custom `MyRoutePrefixAttribute` instead of using the default `[RouteAttribute]` (Feel free to use the `[RouteAttribute]` if you think this behavior should be overrided ):

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyRoutePrefixAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyRoutePrefixAttribute(string prefix) { Prefix = prefix; }
    public string Prefix { get; }
}
```

And to lookup this `[MyRoutePrefixAttribute]` from the inheritance chain, I create a `RoutePrefixConvention` that will combine the prefixes recursively:

```cs
public class RoutePrefixConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
        {
            var prefixes = GetPrefixes(controller.ControllerType);  // [prefix, parentPrefix, grandpaPrefix,...]
            if(prefixes.Count ==  0) continue;
            // combine these prefixes one by one
            var prefixRouteModels = prefixes.Select(p => new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute(p.Prefix)))
                .Aggregate( (acc , prefix)=> AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(prefix, acc));
            selector.AttributeRouteModel =  selector.AttributeRouteModel != null ?
                AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(prefixRouteModels, selector.AttributeRouteModel):
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = prefixRouteModels;
        }
    }

    private IList<MyRoutePrefixAttribute> GetPrefixes(Type controlerType)
    {
        var list = new List<MyRoutePrefixAttribute>();
        FindPrefixesRec(controlerType, ref list);
        list = list.Where(r => r!=null).ToList();
        return list;

        // find [MyRoutePrefixAttribute('...')] recursively 
        void FindPrefixesRec(Type type, ref List<MyRoutePrefixAttribute> results)
        {
            var prefix = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<MyRoutePrefixAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            results.Add(prefix);   // null is valid because it will seek prefix from parent recursively
            var parentType = type.BaseType;
            if(parentType == null) return;
            FindPrefixesRec(parentType, ref results);
        }
    }
}
```

this convention will *NOT* influence the performance: it only searches all the `[MyRoutePrefixAttribute]` attributes through the inheritance chain **at startup time**.

Finally, don't forget to add this convention within your startup:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews(opts =>{
    opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention());
});
```

#### Demo

let's create three controllers to test the above RoutePrefixConvention:

`RootApiController` -> `BaseApiController` -> `TestRouteController`

```cs
[ApiController]
[MyRoutePrefix("root/controllers")]
public class RootApiController : ControllerBase { }

[MyRoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class BaseApiController : RootApiController { }

[Route("testing-route")]
public class TestRouteController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string test()
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

Now when accessing `/root/controllers/api/v1/testing-route`, We'll get a string of  `abc`:

[image: custom route prefix through inheritance]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I think this is something that should be included in the framework itself. Because it's something really needed for big projects.

Comment: Great how-to sample, very useful! Is there any reason why GetPrefixes() is called inside the foreach loop over the controller selectors, and not before the loop?

Comment: @RickyTad Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't notice that since the demo code should only run at startup-time so it would not improve the runtime efficiency too much.. Anyway, it's much better to move the GetPrefixes() out of the loop :)