# .NET 6 - Concatenate routes of base classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

In my code, I have below base class:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("modules/example/v{apiVersion:apiVersion}")]
public abstract class ModuleControllerBase : ControllerBase
{ ... }
```

The data which my API handles sometimes has composite primary keys, for which I have defined another base class inheriting the above:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("subsidiary/{subsidiaryId:int:required}/branch/{branchId:int:required}")]
public abstract class CollectionControllerBase : ModuleControllerBase
{ ... }
```

Then, finally, an implementation of the above classes would look as such:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WorkOrderLineController : CollectionControllerBase
{ ... }
```

My idea was that this would produce a URL like `{api-url}/modules/example/v1/subsidiary/1/branch/3/WorkOrderLine/{some-endpoint-in-WorkOrderLineController}` at runtime.

However, when Swagger opens up in the browser it only shows the route from the implemented controller.[image: The generated endpoint doc by Swagger]

Is there some default configuration that I need to change, or am I misunderstanding something?

I can only find results about handling polymorphic response models.

Comment: I believe with each subsequent class you're re-defining the route URL, overriding the previous one, not creating an additional prefix. This isn't anything to do with Swashbuckle, but ASP.NET Core routing.

Comment: I have never imagined that someone would use routing like this. hats off to you. and like @MartinCostello said , it is nothing to do with swagger but the routing itself.

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks for clarifying that it's ASP.NET Core routing behaviour rather than Swashbuckle. Do you happen to know of any way to make .NET Core concatenate these routes instead of overwriting them?

Comment: @CodingMytra really, is it rare? It seems a fairly common desire to me, to want a base URL when your API grows larger

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58761052/9247039) what you are looking for.

Comment: @CodingMytra thank you, looks very useful! Will definitely look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, the `Route` attribute is "static" in the sense that it simply pulls the route from the string value specified, substituting the `[controller]` token for the controller name.

If you want the behavior you specified, you can either [create a new attribute that implements `IRouteTemplateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-route-attributes-using-iroutetemplateprovider) or [create a custom application model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-application-model-to-customize-attribute-routes).

A custom attribute, e.g. `NestedRouteAttribute`, would probably be easier. I don't have a code example, but here's a description:

You can have the `IRouteTemplateProvider.Template` implementation walk the inheritance tree (using `controller.GetType().BaseType`) until it hits `ControllerBase`. Once you have the list of types, you can iterate through the list from parent(s) to child types, concatenating the values of the `Route` attribute.

Edit: Here's a quick-and-dirty example:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class NestedRouteAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
{
    Type _controllerType;
    string _template;

    public NestedRouteAttribute(string template, Type t)
    {
        _controllerType = t;
        _template = template;
    }

    public string? Template
    {
        get
        {
            // Look up the route from the parent type. This only goes up one level, but if the parent class also has a `NestedRouteAttribute`, then it should work recursively.
            Type? bt  = _controllerType.BaseType;

            IRouteTemplateProvider? routeAttr = bt?.GetCustomAttributes().Where(a => a is IRouteTemplateProvider).FirstOrDefault() as IRouteTemplateProvider;
            return Path.Join(routeAttr?.Template, _template);
        }
    }

    public int? Order => null;

    public string? Name => _template;
}
```

```cs
[Route("api/v1")]
public class MyApiControllerBase : ControllerBase { }
```

```cs
[NestedRoute("api/v1", typeof(MyBranchControllerBase))]
public class MyBranchControllerBase : ControllerBase { }
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[NestedRoute("[controller]", typeof(FooController))]
public class FooController : MyApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string HelloWorld() => "hello, world!";

}
```

Requesting `/api/v1/branch/division/foo` should return `hello, world!`.

Note 1: Since attributes don't have information about the types they're attached to, if you want to get rid of having to use `typeof(FooController)` in the attribute, I think you'll need to go with the custom application model instead. You could also change the API to declare the parent class in the NestedRouteAttribute instead.

Note 2: This only retrieves the first route attribute from the parent class, so this doesn't support multiple route attributes on the same class. That's considered bad practice by Microsoft, but if you need it, I think that's a separate question.

Comment: @CodingMytra, yeah, I recognize that it's not a full answer, but it seemed a little more detailed than to fit in a comment. In any case, I think that the answer you posted helps to fill in more of the gaps.

Comment: @iinuwa thanks for the answer! Trying this now. I think I'm already on the right path, however I'm having trouble setting the new route as the operation's route. I obviously can't write to the `Template` property of the `RouteAttribute` class, and replacing it with a new attribute doesn't seem possible either.

Comment: > replacing it with a new attribute doesn't seem possible either

Could you elaborate on this? I added a quick example to show generally how it would work.

Comment: @iinuwa cheers for the snippets, I got it working now! Only problem with your code is that `Path.Join` combines the strings with a backslash instead of a forward slash. Simply replacing it with `$"{routeAttr?.Template}/{_template}"` returned the desired result. I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yes, I was running on Linux, so that makes sense. Glad it worked for you!