# Change only the controller name in the route having an inherited Base Controller class in .NET 7

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, attributes, .net-7.0

I'm implementing an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application.

The controllers part is managed with a base class (which actually has the `Route` attribute which I am going to complete by adding the template on the individual action methods) and from which the others inherit.

`BaseController` class:

```cs
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public abstract class BaseApiController<TController> : ControllerBase
     where TController : ControllerBase
{
    // some code
}
```

Example of a controller class that inherits from `BaseController`:

```cs
public class AuthApiController : BaseApiController<AuthApiController>
{
    public AuthApiController(ILogger<AuthApiController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IUserService? userService)
        : base(logger, httpContextAccessor, userService: userService) { }

   [HttpGet("new")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewUser()
   {
       // some code
   }
}
```

This way the route of the `CreateNewUser` action is: `/api/v1/authapi/new`.

My goal is to make `authapi` just `auth` (`/api/v1/auth/new`), so I was wondering if there is an `attribute` or another way to "merge" the route rule of the base controller and the various templates on the actions with the name of the individual controllers also customizable.

Comment: Why not rename your controller to AuthController?

Comment: @SBFrancies I wanted to make a separation between the mvc controllers and the api ones, but eventually I will do this if there are no other ways

Answer (score 0):

You could override the route of a specific action different from the controler use `~`
Try following

```
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("new")]
        public void test()
        {

        }
        [HttpPost("~/api/v1/auth/new")]
        public void test2()
        {
        }
    }
```

[image]

Or maybe change the whole controller path use

```
    [Route("api/v1/auth")]
    [ApiController]
```

Comment: It certainly works like this, but I wanted to avoid having to repeat the same route on all the actions

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

As suggested [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72939348/9349802) I implemented a `custom attribute` that combine the route joining the template of the two classes:

```cs
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
 public class ControllerNestedRouteAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
 {
     private readonly Type _controllerType;

     public ControllerNestedRouteAttribute(string template, Type controllerType)
     {
         Name = template;
         _controllerType = controllerType;
     }

    public string Template
    {
        get
        {
            // Look up the route from the parent type. This only goes up one level, but if the parent class also has a `NestedRouteAttribute`, then it should work recursively.
            Type? baseType = _controllerType.BaseType;

            IRouteTemplateProvider? baseTypeRouteAttr = baseType?.GetCustomAttributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a is IRouteTemplateProvider) as IRouteTemplateProvider;
            string? baseTypeRouteAttrTemplate = baseTypeRouteAttr?.Template;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseTypeRouteAttrTemplate))
            {
                if (baseTypeRouteAttrTemplate.EndsWith('/'))
                    return Path.Join(baseTypeRouteAttrTemplate, Name);
                else
                    return Path.Join(baseTypeRouteAttrTemplate, "/", Name);
            }

            return Name;
        }
    }

     public int? Order => null;

     public string Name { get; }
 }
```

and in the inherited class:

```cs
[ControllerNestedRoute("auth", typeof(AuthApiController))]
public class AuthApiController : BaseApiController<AuthApiController>
{
    public AuthApiController(ILogger<AuthApiController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IUserService? userService)
        : base(logger, httpContextAccessor, userService: userService) { }

   [HttpGet("new")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewUser()
   {
       // some code
   }
}
```

and in the base controller:

```cs
 [Route("api/v1")]
 [ApiController]
 public abstract class BaseApiController<TController> : ControllerBase
     where TController : ControllerBase
 {
   // ...
 }
```

Now i can call the action with the route that i wanted `/api/v1/auth/new`.