# Fallback to SPA in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

##### Brief

I have a web api written in .NET 7 and a React SPA. I am trying to host them in IIS under the same host name (as a single website).
I want to achieve the following things:

1. When I make a request to `/api/books`, it should be routed to the **API** (server-side routing).
2. When I make a request to `/books`, it should be routed to the **SPA** (client-side routing).
3. If the path doesn't match any of the routes or the API returns 404, it should fallback to the **SPA**.

##### Program.cs

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseProblemDetails();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

var isSwaggerEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(builder.Configuration["ApiDocumentationEnabled"]);

if (isSwaggerEnabled)
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((document, _) =>
        {
            document.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new() { Url = "/api" } };
        });
    });

    app.UseSwaggerUI(options => { options.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1); });
    app.UseReDoc(options => { options.RoutePrefix = "redoc"; });
}

app.MapHealthChecks("/health",
        new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("core"),
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });

app.MapHealthChecksUI();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

await app.RunAsync();
```

##### Problems

1. None of my controllers have the `/api` prefix. If I take the BooksController as an example, it would have its route attribute as `[Route("books")]`. So first problem is that I want to add a global `/api` prefix to all the API controllers. This can be achieved using a `UsePathBase` and `UseRouting` calls ([Relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72112152/19432545)). However, this poses another problem. AFAIK, `UsePathBase` extracts the prefix `api` from the **Path** and postpends it to the **PathBase**. This will lead to routing conflicts as after the `UseRouting` call both `/books` and `/api/books` will be routed to **BooksController**.
2. Moreover, even if there are no conflicts in **API** and **SPA** routes, it still doesn't fallback to SPA routing (serve the index.html file).

##### Explored directions and possible workarounds

1. To try and resolve point 2 in **Problems**, I tried moving `app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html")` to immediately after `UseCors` call. Didn't work.
2. I could manually add the `api` prefix to all controllers or add a common BaseController which has the route prefix using a [custom route attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58761052/19432545). Not tried yet.

##### References and useful links

1. [Andrew Lock's Blog on PathBase](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-pathbase-in-aspnetcore/#using-the-pathbasemiddleware-to-strip-off-a-prefix)
2. [Kristian Hellang's SpaFallback middleware](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware?tab=readme-ov-file#spafallback-)

Comment: You can add a global prefix to all API controllers by creating a custom routing convention.